# Bypass windows authentication for SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, single-sign-on

I have a web server that serves a report using SQL reporting services. Is there a way to bypass the windows authentication and pass in somekind of  token?

We have a website that the user logins to and then a link inside their account page that links to the report server.  We don't want to prompt them to login again.

What is a good way to do this?

Based on the custom authentication, I would provide a custom login:

http://myserver/mycustomSSRSLogin

Once I make the call to the login url?

Do I just redirect to the reporting url: http://myserver/mySalesReport?

Comment: [Custom Authentication in Reporting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152899%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I saw that article. Is there a good full example?  I don't understand how once it is authenticated, do I pass something to the report URL.?

Comment: http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/ ?